# Backing up Google Drive on a different storage device on Chrome OS

Tags: google-drive, backup, chrome-os

I am very interested in a way to back up Chrome OS's Google Drive content onto another storage device besides the local disk, like maybe an SD card.

This would provide me more space to store files for offline work and also allow me to transfer files from Ubuntu and Chrome OS easily.

I was wondering if you could help me achieve this?